# Pandas groupby() and agg() method confusion on columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Can I check what is the difference between

```
df[['column1', 'column2']].groupby('column1').agg(['mean', 'count'])
```

and

```
df[['column1', 'column2']].groupby('column1').agg({'column2': 'mean', 'column2': 'count'})
```

In the first example, `mean` and `count` is performed on `column2` which is not in `groupby`.

In the second example, same logic but I had explicitly mentioned `column2` in `agg`.

Why do I not see the same result for both?

Comment: in the second example, your dictionary has two of the same keys, which is not possible. The dictionary would only keep the last key, so im assuming your result only returned the count and not the mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TLDR

The problem with the second statement has to due with overwriting the column.

---

There are at least three ways to do this statement.

First let's build a test dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
from seaborn import load_dataset

df_tips = load_dataset('tips')

df_tips.head()
```

###### Statement 1: Same as your first wy

```
df_tips[['sex','size']].groupby(['sex']).agg(['mean','count'])
```

Output:

```
            size      
            mean count
sex                   
Male    2.630573   157
Female  2.459770    87
```

A dataframe with a multiindex column header size and level=1 both aggregations.

###### Statement 2: Using a list of aggregrations for 'size' in a dictionary

```
df_tips[['sex','size']].groupby(['sex']).agg({'size':['mean','count']})
```

Output (same as above)

```
            size      
            mean count
sex                   
Male    2.630573   157
Female  2.459770    87
```

###### Statement 3: Using [named aggregrations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation)

```
df_tips[['sex','size']].groupby(['sex']).agg(mean_size=('size','mean'),count_size=('size','count'))
```

Output:

```
        mean_size  count_size
sex                          
Male     2.630573         157
Female   2.459770          87
```

This give a dataframe with a 'flatten' column header that you name yourself, however that name must not contain a space or special characters.

###### The ***incorrect*** way is your second method

```
df_tips[['sex','size']].groupby(['sex']).agg({'size':'mean','size':'count'})
```

Outputs:

```
        size
sex         
Male     157
Female    87
```

What is happening here is that you are getting two columns one for each aggregations but the column header is the same 'size', therefore the first iteration is getting overwritten with the second 'count' in this case.